# How to deploy maven parent pom.xml into artifactory?

Tags: maven, repository, artifactory, parent-pom

I created a pom.xml which contains my general dependencies. I want to add this pom into our inhouse repository (Artifactory) and then want to use it in all of my maven modules pom files as defining .

I can install the parent pom.xml into M2 and use it successfully but after I deployed the parent pom into Artifactory other poms can't download parent pom from Artifactory. I am sure that my inhouse repository settings are correct in `settings.xml`.

Is there a success way for this purpose?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `child poms can't reach parent pom` what does it mean ? (i.e. what's the error message ? can you post the logs?)

Comment: @ben75 i changed it. i mean my child pom can not download parent pom from artifactory.

Comment: what command did you use to deploy ? was it successful ? do you see your parent pom in artifactory when you browse it (using web UI) ? can you post the logs of the error when building child ?

Comment: what about this ominous "can't reach"? Are you sure your parent section of the child's pom.xml does not contain "relativePath"?